# SQLite same column name on join

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Using sqlite on android studio, I have two related tables "A" and "B", that both have a column "id". When I make a join on Android Studio, and try to get the value from "id" I get "B.id" whether I put

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("A.id")); // or
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

I'm considering changing the name of the columns so I can distinguish them easily, but I've seen that sqlite doesn't have any simple thing like "Alter Table "A" rename column", but I would have to duplicate the table with the correct name and deleting the old one so I'm trying to avoid this solution.

Also a solution I thought is to duplicate the column in the query putting something like "Select A.id, * from...", but is something I'd rather avoid.

Any idea why the code I posted might not work? Thanks

Comment: Why not using aliases? `SELECT A.id AS ID_A ...` By the way, the keyword `AS` is optional and can be omitted.

Comment: I'm selecting using * instead of putting every column.

Comment: Can you show us the table fields? Is A the master table? how are A and B being linked. Can we see your select clause?

Answer (score 2):

Define an alias on the columns, optionally selecting all other columns with `*`.  These are not mutually exclusive, so the following will work:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id, * FROM ...
```

It will return the aliased columns along with all others, even if the data is redundant:

```
Columns: a_id, b_id, id, ..., id, ...
```

Frankly, you can't avoid all solutions.  The two solutions that you already listed are about all you have to choose from.  Sqlite does not automatically prefix table names to the column names, so there are really no other options.

Answer (score 2):

With a Cursor you can (albeit it not recommended) use specific offsets *(what the getColumnIndex method does is return the offset, the get???? methods all take on offset)*.

So say the query was `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.maptoAid` and

- Table *A* has columns:-

  - **id** *(offset **0**)* and
  - **name** *(offset **1**)*
- and Table **B** has columns:-

  - **id** and *(offset **2**)*
  - **maptoAid** *(offset **3**)* and
  - **blah** *(offset **4**)*

Then (for the above only, the offsets have to be determined)

to get **A.id** use `cursor.getInt(0);`
to get **B.id** use `cursor.getInt(2);`

**Note** The use of offsets is discouraged far better to use column aliases (**AS**) along with the Cursor **getColumnIndex** method.

- offsets are not tolerant of changes to the query, that is change the number or order of columns and offsets may have to be re-calculated.
- names, via the getColumnIndex method (unless duplicating the same name) are tolerant of such changes

Such as

```
SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid .... other columns (aliased or not) .... FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.maptoAid
```

Or easier to code bit with greater overheads

```
SELECT *, A.id AS aid, B.id  FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.maptoAid
```

and then use :-

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("aid"));
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("bid"));
```

> I get "B.id" whether I put ...
>   and
>   Any idea why the code I posted might not work?

The reason why you get **B.id** is that the **`getColumnindex`** method doesn't finish looping when it finds the column BUT continues the loop, thus returning the last if there are more than one columns with the same name.

Also note (unless fixed) that the Cursor **`getColumnIndex`** method is also case sensitive. So `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Aid"))` would return **-1**.